# Phonegap Build is packing entire resources folder into each platform package?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have recently created a mobile application that I build for iOS and Android using PhoneGap. I am currently trying to migrate to using PhoneGap Build and am having semi success. The issue I'm having is that my resources folder is constructed like so :

/res 
/res/icons/android 
/res/icons/ios 
/res/screens/android 
/res/screens/ios 
I then have, in my config.xml, entries like so :

```
<!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />

<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
```

When PhoneGap Build creates my packages, they seem quite large - I noticed that, in my android apk, it has correctly copied the right files into the res/drawable folder so the application is working correctly but the problem is that it has left the entire res folder with all the iOS and Android resources in my www folder - which have of course been packaged in the apk!  
Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see this guy deleting them manually although I don't like this!

http://www.slideshare.net/KimPropertyPattaya/decrease-apk-files-size-after-phonegap-build

Basically the guy unzips the apk, removes the files that are not needed and zips it back again.